# Making Wii Sports Tennis burn more energy

Tags: wii-sports

How can I play Wii Sports Tennis to make it burn more calories/energy? Notes:

- I realize that, even played differently, Wii Tennis doesn't 
  qualify as exercise.
- One way to burn more energy is to never serve, and always 
  receive. That way, you don't get the "power serve" advantage where 
  you "automatically" win the point w/ virtually no effort when the 
  opponent can't return the serve.
- Another way: I'm right-handed, and now play with my left hand, on 
  the theory it requires more energy to co-ordinate my weaker hand 
  (true?).

These methods help slightly, but are there others?

I considered taping the WiiMote to my arm and then swinging my arm to 
control the racket, but I'm guessing that won't be very playable.

I realize the Wii Fit qualifies as exercise, but find the games boring 
after a while.

Another game I'd like to "burn more energy" in is Wii Mario Kart.

Comment: Did you consider playing real-life tennis instead?

Comment: I know a lot of people are getting into this "real life" thing, but I think it's just a fad. Plus, I believe real-life tennis requires interacting with a real-life human being, and I've heard those things can be hard to control.

Answer (score 4):

The only way you'll burn reasonable calories in any of these games (Kinect games included) is to hook everything to a stationary bike, and [pedal to keep your TV either powered on](http://scienceshareware.com/bicycle-generator-faq.htm#television), or descrambled.  You'll never hit your target heart rate playing Wii Tennis or Mario Kart.

EDIT -- perhaps another approach is to tie your Wiimote to something bowflex-like, so that you have to exert more energy to swing.  :)  Not sure how you could actually implement something like that, though.  I imagine it would be okay if you were only hitting forehands, but switching to the backhand side would probably be challenging.

Comment: Interesting picture of someone trying to play Wii Tennis while riding a bike.

Comment: I was thinking more about the general "is wii any good for exercise" question.  :)  haha!  It would make sense for Mario Kart, though!

Comment: It actually doesn't take that much energy to run a TV/Wii, and I think I need something where game performance is tied to the exercise/exertion. Losing the TV screen definitely would affect my game performance, but that's not quite what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Just stand up.... here is an article about the benefits standing up at your desk at work... while you are asking about games I imagine the effects would be the same.

[Standing up at work](http://blogs.hbr.org/your-health-at-work/2010/08/the-many-benefits-of-standing.html)

Comment: good point.  I'm actually trying to get a standup desk for the office.

Comment: I know that it's possible to play Wii Tennis sitting down, but I've always played it standing up. I even move around a little, although I realize it doesn't help my game (I just get caught up in it).